# Bizarre ternary operator behavior in debugger on x64 platform

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ternary-operator

I'm using a very simple ternary expression in my C# code:

```
helperClass.SomeData = helperClass.HasData ? GetSomeData() : GetSomeOtherData();
```

In both cases, the functions on each path of the expression return a non-null object, but if I look at the result in the debugger, it is null until I reference it in the code such as using an assert:

```
Debug.Assert(helperClass.SomeData != null);
```

This only appears to happen if I use an "x64" or "Any CPU" platform setting in Debug mode. It's fine in "x86" mode.

I try to be very cautious before assuming I've found a bug in the compiler or debugger, but I can't find any other explanation for this behavior.

Here's a full class to do a repro, just call SomeClass.SomeAction() in the debugger in x64 mode and step through to see it:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public bool HasData;
    public object SomeData;

    private SomeClass() {
        HasData = false;
    }

    public static void SomeAction() {
        var helperClass = new SomeClass();
        // Exhibits weird debugger behavior of having helperClass.SomeData = null after this line:
        helperClass.SomeData = helperClass.HasData ? GetSomeData() : GetSomeOtherData();

        // Note that trying helperClass.SomeData.ToString() returns a debugger error saying SomeData is null

        // But this code is just fine
        //if(helperClass.HasData) {
        //    helperClass.SomeData = GetSomeData();
        //} 
        //else {
        //    helperClass.SomeData = GetSomeOtherData();
        //}

        // In both cases though, after this line things are fine:
        Debug.Assert(helperClass.SomeData != null);
    }

    private static object GetSomeData() {
        return new object();
    }

    private static object GetSomeOtherData() {
        return new object();
    }
}
```

**Am I missing something or is this a bug in the x64 debugger?** I'm using debug mode so no optimizations should be present.

Comment: Note that *debug symbols generated* and *optimizations generated* are actually orthogonal. It is legal, though somewhat unusual, to turn on debug symbols and optimizations at the same time. Might want to double-check that you are not in that odd configuration.

Comment: The "Optimize code" checkbox under the "Build" tab is unchecked for my active (Debug/x64) configuration. Should I check somewhere else?

Comment: Nope; sounds like that isn't the problem.

Comment: just tried it (optimize code off, debug on) and can see the described behaviour - in x86 diractly after the line SomeData != null while in x64 it "becomes != null" when first accessed (not from debugger but in code)... could be interesting to compare what the generated IL looks like...

Comment: I repro on VS2010 SP1.  The debugger loses its marbles pretty badly at that statement.  Adding a line and setting a breakpoint on it doesn't work either.  You can report the bug at connect.microsoft.com.  Debugging the x86 build is generally highly advisable.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Can you confirm this is a bug? If so, is there already a Connect case for it?

Comment: @Jeff: It certainly sounds like it is a bug, but I have not reproduced it and so I cannot confirm it. Sounds like a good candidate for posting on Connect. I do not know if there is already a case. I note that over the years there have been a number of odd bugs involving code generation and debugging for the conditional operator; the precise CLR rules for determining statically what the known type of a stack slot is can be a bit tricky and that leads to bugs. It would not surprise me if this were another one of those, but like I said, I haven't personally repro'd it.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks, I've filed a Connect bug for this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/684202

Comment: @Eric I use that "pdb with opt on" all the time. If your app is in house you get nicer stack traces (line numbers, if occasionally taken with a pinch of salt) with them present at the cost of deploying more bits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taking Eric Lippert's advice that this is probably a bug, I've filed an official Connect bug for this issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/684202

Thanks everyone for your feedback!

**UPDATE**: They got back to me and said they've fixed this corner case in the next version of the compiler. Hooray! :)

Answer (score 4):

to me this doesn't seem a bug in the debugger but possibly of the compiler...

when changing the code to

```
{ helperClass.SomeData = helperClass.HasData ? GetSomeData() : GetSomeOtherData(); }
```

the IL generated is different and the debugger works as expected...

Comment: Why should you have to put {}'s around it?

Comment: I don't say you have to... just something that seemed working after Reflector gaved me some weird code when disassembling that line...

Comment: It seems like a bug (perhaps just in the compiler as you suggest). I'm working around it by converting it to an if statement even though ReSharper thinks I'm an idiot for doing that :)

Comment: nevermind what ReSharper says in this case... except ReSharper has some brilliant idea to solve it :-)