# x86 vs AnyCPU returning different results on .Max() when used with ternary operator

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ternary-operator, conditional-operator, anycpu

https://github.com/qntmfred/FooTimestamp

The following program in the AnyCPU build configuration evaluates `maxTimestamp` as `DateTime.MinValue`.

```
public class Foo
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>() { new Foo() { Timestamp = new DateTime(2012, 7, 1) } };
        var maxTimestamp = foos.Any() ? foos.Max(x => x.Timestamp) : new DateTime(2012, 7, 2);
    } // put a breakpoint here - maxTimestamp evaluates to DateTime.MinValue
}
```

* I've been chasing this bug from a couple different angles since I first posted this, so the comments probably don't make much sense. See the revision history if you want to see it all but I've scrapped most of the original post to focus on what I have now simplified this problem to.

Comment: EF doesn't apply here any more since you threw the items into a list.

Comment: I didn't think so either, but I listed it anyways just in case somebody knew something I didn't about how EF might be causing this - the objects are still `DynamicProxy`s so I thought it might be plausible

Comment: Looks like it should work to me.. How much simplification have you applied to this code?

Comment: As a debugging tip, try using a different value instead of `DataTime.MinValue` and see if you get the value you set.

Comment: good idea @JeffMercado that returned `DateTime.MinValue` too

Comment: @qntmfred, _fooRepository.GetAll().ToList() returns a List, an IList os something else? I'm running the same code here and it's giving the expected results (not this DateTime.MinValue thing).

Comment: .GetAll() returns an IQueryable<Foo>, .ToList() then of course returns a List<Foo>

Comment: As that's the case, it would help to see what your `foo` objects look like.  `DateTime.MinValue` corresponds to the default value of a `DateTime`. It looks like something is failing somewhere so you just get back default values for all your items.  Verify that the list contains foos that have reasonable values and their timestamps are not set to the default value.

Comment: I can hover inspect `foos` and see recent timestamps in the objects and I still get the `DateTime.MinValue` for `maxTimestamp`

Comment: Is the Foo.Timestamp-property of type DateTime?

Comment: Yes Foo.Timestamp is of type DateTime

Comment: are you using some kind of code postprocessing stuff like code contracts?

Comment: Did you try to use a manually created list instead of pulling the list from the repo, like `var foos = new List<Foo> { new Foo { Timestamp = ... }, new Foo { Timestamp = ... }, ...}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like this ended up being a bona fide compiler bug. neat. It's been fixed in .NET 4.5

[Bizarre ternary operator behavior in debugger on x64 platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067354/bizarre-ternary-operator-behavior-in-debugger-on-x64-platform)
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/684202